# jquery just works for the latest button not all button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My PHP HTML code is this :

```
<?php 

foreach($questions as $question){
    echo"
    <div id='postShare'>            
        <div class='col-md-10 col-md-offset-1' id='listPost'>
            <div class='list-group'>    
                <li class='list-group-item text-center '>
                    <span class='pull-left' id='question_author'>".$question->author."</span>
                    &nbsp;
                    <span class='pull-right' id='question_time'><p>".time_ago($question->time)."</p></span>
                    <hr>
                    <span class='pull-right' style='color:red;font-size:11px;'>سوال</span>
                    <br>
                    <center><h4 id='question_title'>"  .$question->title. "</h4></center>
                    <hr>
                    <span class='pull-right' style='color:blue;font-size:11px;'>توضیحات</span>
                    <br>
                    <h5 id='question_desc'>".$question->description."</h5>
                    <hr>            
                    <span class='pull-right' style='color:GoldenRod;font-size:11px;'>کد برنامه</span>
                    <br>
                    <pre id='question_code'>".$question->code."</pre>
                    <hr>
                    <button class='btn btn-primary' id='send_answer'>پاسخگویی به این سوال</button>
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";
}

?>
```

and my Jquery file is this :

```
$(function(){
    $("#send_answer").click(function(e){  
        alert("cliked");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This PHP code just fetch and show the database data with a button.
I want to when I click at that button it shows an alert. its work for the latest data that fetch and do not work for all.

Comment: Because you're duplicating `id` values in your HTML.  Which is invalid, so the behavior of the JavaScript is undefined.

Comment: This is illegal -- you're creating buttons with the same ID. Use a class, not an id for looped elements.

Comment: @SterlingArcher "illegal"?  Do you mean "invalid"?

Comment: ok thanks guys but what i must do for this problem

Comment: @Amirh_ba: You must not use the same `id` values multiple times on the same page.  Maybe use a `class` instead and modify your jQuery selector to target that?

Comment: @freedomn-m no, I meant what I said. Means the same thing, but the spec does not define "illegal" vs "invalid" in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create button with the same `class`. Creating with a same `id` will result in only one to be operated on.

PHP

```
 <?php 
     foreach($questions as $question) {
         echo "
            <div id='postShare'>
                <div class='col-md-10 col-md-offset-1' id='listPost'>
                     <div class='list-group'>    
                        <li class='list-group-item text-center '>
                            <span class='pull-left' id='question_author'>".$question->author."</span>&nbsp;
                            <span class='pull-right' id='question_time'><p>".time_ago($question->time)."</p></span><hr>
                            <span class='pull-right' style='color:red;font-size:11px;'>سوال</span><br><center><h4 id='question_title'>"  .$question->title. "</h4></center><hr>
                            <span class='pull-right' style='color:blue;font-size:11px;'>توضیحات</span><br><h5 id='question_desc'>".$question->description."</h5><hr>            
                            <span class='pull-right' style='color:GoldenRod;font-size:11px;'>کد برنامه</span><br><pre id='question_code'>".$question->code."</pre><hr>
                            <button class='btn btn-primary send_answer'>پاسخگویی به این سوال</button>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>";
     }
 ?>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $(".send_answer").click(function(e) {
        alert("cliked");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```